# Copula Value At Risk

Tags: statistics, matlab

Has anyone of you any experience in copula Value At Risk with Matlab?
In Matlab I've written this code:

```
copula='Normale, Normale';
        B=handles.array;
        [~, n]=size(handles.array);
        for i=1:n
            phat(:,i)=mle(handles.array(:,i))
        end 
        p_1=normcdf(handles.array(:,1), phat(1,1), phat(2,1));
        p_2=normcdf(handles.array(:,2), phat(1,2), phat(2,2));
        handles.p1=p_1;
        handles.p2=p_2;
        handles.matrici.Mdati=[handles.array handles.port p_1 p_2];
        U=[handles.p1 handles.p2];
        handles.U=U;

        guidata(handles.figure1, handles);
```

and

```
copula='Normale';
        RHOHAT=copulafit('Gaussian', handles.U);
        figure(1)
        scatterhist(handles.U(:,1), handles.U(:,2));
        for i=1:100
        U=copularnd('Gaussian', RHOHAT, 10000);
        X=[norminv(U(:,1),0,1) norminv(U(:,2),0,1)];
        port_ret=X*handles.w';
        axes(handles.axes1)
        plot(port_ret, 'k')
        legend('Rendimenti simulati')
```

My problem is I don't want a single value for VaR but n values to be plotted against returns.

Can anyone help me??

Comment: Some comments in the code would help! Where does VaR even come into your code? Also what is your code supposed to do? And what is `for i=1:100` for??? Since you never use `i` and there is no `end`...

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Basically VaR should be something like norminv(P,0, Sigma).
My questions are: 1)where do i get sigma? 
2) "for" will match with an end, probably I forgot it. My idea is: perform i times copularnd, X and after all the iteitions, save VaR values and plot it against portfolio returns (these returns are uploaded via Excel File).

How can I do this?
Maybe Sigmas come from standard deviations of X.

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (value, risk) will not help categorize it.  *Always* be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!